# getting an extra OR before the search

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfquery

I have this query and i m am getting an extra OR after the AND clause and the search is failing

```
<cfset CountVar = 1>
        <cfquery name="qFiltered">
            SELECT id,name,email,useris,roleid
            FROM users
            WHERE 1=1
                <cfif search NEQ "">
                    AND (
                        <cfloop list="#aColumnArray#" index="sSearch">
                            <cfif CountVar NEQ countOfColumns> OR </cfif> 
                            #sSearch# LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#search#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
                            <cfset CountVar += 1>
                        </cfloop>
                    )
                </cfif>
            
        </cfquery>
```

Something is wrong in the counter where it is not validating the number of countofColumns

```
<cfset var countOfColumns = listLen(aColumnArray)>
```

Comment: You should consider renaming `aColumnArray` if that's actually a string/list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
 <cfquery name="qFiltered">
        SELECT id,name,email,useris,roleid
        FROM users
        WHERE 1 = 1
        <cfif search NEQ "">
            AND (
                0 = 1 
                <cfloop list="#aColumnArray#" index="sSearch">
                   OR 
                   [#sSearch#] LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#search#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
                </cfloop>
              )
        </cfif>
  </cfquery>
```

Comment: Even when it's correct, it would be good if you explained the logic behind this briefly.

Answer (score 2):

The basic logic here is prepending `OR` for all WHERE conditions after the first one:

```
<cfset CountVar = 1>
<cfloop list="#aColumnArray#" index="sSearch">
    <cfif CountVar gt 1> OR </cfif> 
    #sSearch# LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#search#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
    <cfset CountVar++>
</cfloop>
```

First iteration has no OR, all subsequent one have OR in front.

Btw.: A LIKE with a leading wildcard cannot use the index and will result in poor performance. Consider a FULLTEXT index.